# Removing specific text and characters from dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Having a list like this (only way bigger) called 'data_list':

```
2017-04-01, available
2017-04-02, available
2017-04-01, available
2017-04-02, available
2017-04-02, available
2017-04-01, available
2017-04-02, available
2017-04-01, available
2017-04-02, available
2017-04-01, available
etcetera
```

I used the following code,

```
dates = collections.defaultdict(list)
for date, xyz in data_list:
    dates[date].append(xyz)
counts = {date: collections.Counter(xyz) for date, xyz in dates.items()}
```

To create a dictionary like this:

```
2017-04-01,Counter({'available': 9})
2017-04-02,Counter({'available': 12})
2017-04-03,Counter({'available': 9})
2017-04-04,Counter({'available': 4})
2017-04-05,Counter({'available': 9})
2017-04-06,Counter({'available': 2})
```

How would I proceed in removing "Counter"? (and eventually characters like '(' and '{')

Currently, I have this code. But it doesn't do anything.

```
for x in my_dictionary:
try:
    x = x.replace('Counter','')
except:
    pass
```

The main goal eventually is to get a .csv file like this:

```
date, available
2017-04-01, 9
2017-04-02, 12
2017-04-03, 9
2017-04-04, 4
2017-04-05, 9
2017-04-06, 2
```

Part of print output of the dictionary:

```
'2018-12-12': Counter({'available': 3}), '2018-04-28': Counter({'available': 4}), '2017-12-16': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-17': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-14': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-15': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-12': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-13': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-10': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-11': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-18': Counter({'available': 2}), '2017-12-19': Counter({'available': 2}), '2018-05-31': Counter({'available': 4}), '2018-05-30': Counter({'available': 4}),
```

Comment: You're desire output is not a list. Also those `Counters` are `collections.Counter` objects (not string) that you can simply access to the key and value if you want.

Comment: It used to be a dictionary, which I converted to a list with "for x in counts.items(): listcalender.append(x)" . Where "counts" is the orignal dictionary. So you say it's better to keep the dictionary and remove the characters there?

Comment: Yes, if you can get your items from dictionary that'd be a better way. Also even your items are still complex objects you can parse them of get your expected items in a nested loop, or the whole operations in a list comprehension.

Comment: But how would I tackle a problem like that? Using a dictionary is very new for me. Eventually I need to output a .csv in a way as shown above.

Comment: Probably it would be easier to understand if you also put the code you used to create the dictionary or at least specify what the dictionary contains exactly: what you have written looks like a list of list that contain also a dictionary. The best way would probably be to copy/paste the output of `print my_dictionary`.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia Thank for the tips, I've updates the question as per your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You can get available count by using `available` key to get from counter, like so:

```
counts = {date: collections.Counter(xyz)['available'] for date, xyz in dates.items()}


import csv

def to_row(date, counter):
     return date, counter['booked'], counter['blocked'], counter['available']

counts = [to_row(date, collections.Counter(xyz)) for date, xyz in dates.items()]

 writer = csv.writer(open('<filename>.csv', 'w'))
 writer.writerows(counts)
```

Comment: This does the trick indeed. How would I adapt this piece of code so I can take 3 states?  Like booked, blocked and available.

Comment: How do you want to return it? As a dictionary of date and tuple of states?

Comment: Seeing you want it as CSV, returning as a list of list seems the way to go. `[[date, booked, blocked, available], ...]`. You can then use `writerows` in CSVWriter to write the list.

Comment: Where would I place  [[date, booked, blocked, available], ...] ? Sorry, I'm fairly new to Python but I feel I'm very close to the right answer. The format of the returing output should be what works best as to converting it to a .csv

Comment: It gives an 'invalid syntax' error at the ' * ' at *to_states

Comment: Oh, I missed that tuple unpacking in list comprehensions isn't supported.  How about you have a function that just formats the row? Updated the answer to do just this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `collections.Counter` in this case at all, and you can do away even with `collections.defaultdict`. This will do the trick:

```
dates = {}
for date, value in data_list:
    if value == "available":
        dates[date] = dates.get(date, 0) + 1
# dates contains (date, count) pairs
```

and should be considerably faster, too. Then you can use `csv.writer` or `csv.DictWriter` (in dependence of your desired output CSV) to write out your final CSV. For example:

```
import csv

data_list = [['2017-04-01', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-01', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-01', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-01', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-01', 'available']]

dates = {}
for date, value in data_list:
    if value == "available":
        dates[date] = dates.get(date, 0) + 1

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:  # open output.csv for writing
    writer = csv.writer(f)  # create a csv.writer
    writer.writerow(("date", "available"))  # write our header
    for row in dates.iteritems():  # sorted(dates.iteritems()) instead for date-sorted output
        writer.writerow(row)  # write the row
```

gets you a valid CSV as:

```
date,available
2017-04-02,5
2017-04-01,5
```

and you can open it in pretty much any spreadsheet app. If you want to format it like your output instead, beware that's not a valid CSV.

**UPDATE** - A version with multiple available values for each date (at this point using `collections.Counter` becomes more convenient, but to keep with the theme):

```
import csv

data_list = [['2017-04-01', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-01', 'booked'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'booked'],
             ['2017-04-01', 'available'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'blocked'],
             ['2017-04-01', 'blocked'],
             ['2017-04-02', 'blocked'],
             ['2017-04-01', 'available']]

dates = {}
values = set()  # just so we know what are possible values for the latter CSV header
for date, value in data_list:
    values.add(value)
    dates.setdefault(date, {})[value] = dates.get(date, {}).get(value, 0) + 1

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:  # open output.csv for writing
    header = ["date"] + list(values)  # set header to date,<available_values>
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    writer.writeheader()
    for k, v in dates.iteritems():  # sorted(dates.iteritems()) instead for date-sorted output
        v.update({"date": k})  # add the date to our row
        writer.writerow(v)  # write the row
```

Creates `output.csv` as:

```
date,available,booked,blocked
2017-04-02,2,1,2
2017-04-01,3,1,1
```

You can have as many 'value' fields as you want so it doesn't have to be 3 only.

Comment: Would this also work if there are 3 possible states? Like booked and blocked for example? So after each date there can be 3 number: amount of booked, blocked and available.

Comment: Yes, if you're only interested in the `available` state. If you need all three states `collections.Counter` might be a bit more convenient (and a lot more maintainable) but you can get the same effect with `dates.setdefault(date, {})[value] = dates.get(date, {}).get(value, 0) + 1` instead of checking if the `value == "available"` and counting only the available entries - that would give you a dict with all the counts as an output. You'd then need to use `csv.DictWriter` (or calculate positions manually) when writing to CSV.

Comment: Where would you need to put dates.setdefault(date, {})[value] = dates.get(date, {}).get(value, 0) + 1 in your code to make it work? I'm fairly new to python. Sorry.

Comment: So I get the count of the three states, not only 'available'